# How to return the most recent channel entry/comment date?

Tags: expressionengine

To be honest I'm not expecting an answer to this question. While it sounds simple, I think it's probably quite involved.

For a given channel I want to return one date/time - it will be *either* the latest channel entry date or the most recent comment date, whichever is the most recent date/time.

Cheers
Lee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Statistics Module (as John said) but the following code will output either the comment or entry data like you requested:

```
{exp:stats}
  {if last_comment_date > last_entry_date}
    {!-- Comment is more recent --}
    {last_comment_date format="..."}
  {if:else}
    {!-- Entry is more recent --}
    {last_entry_date format="..."}
  {/if}
{/exp:stats}
```

Comment: John and Jason - huge thanks for helping me out on this. I totally over looked exp:stats. FIY, when comparing dates you have to use the format="..." like {if "{last_comment_date format='%Y %m %d'}" > "{last_entry_date format='%Y %m %d'}"}

Comment: I tested the conditional with the exact code that I posted and it worked. Strange that it didn't for you.

Comment: I think the code 'appears' to work, but the contents of if:else is always returned. Have you tried adding a comment to a channel?

Comment: Not going to work because the variables are not supported as conditionals. see: http://expressionengine.com/forums/viewthread/229421/#1040552

Comment: I retested the code and I guess it doesn't work after all. Not sure what the Stack Overflow process is with correct answers that aren't correct. Although it will be correct if they implement your feature request.

Answer (score 6):

Use the Stats Module here to return the required data

http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/statistics/index.html#variables

```
{exp:stats}
            Last Comment Date : {last_comment_date format="%m/%d/%Y %h:%i %a"}
            Last Entry Date : {last_entry_date format="%m/%d/%Y %h:%i %a"}
    {/exp:stats}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try using the IfElse plugin to make sure you don't output the IfElse conditional.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I reported the problem here: http://expressionengine.com/forums/viewthread/229421, let's see what they say.